# Find control m characters and remove it

Tags: shell, unix

Is there is any single line command to recursively find the .ctl file in all the directories and remove the control m characters from it?

Comment: Yes, there is ...

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk : Can you please share? I was able to achieve it after switching to directory but i would like to find easier solution

Answer (score 2):

Use `find` with `sed`.

With GNU sed:

```
find . -name "*ctl" -type f -exec sed -i 's,^M,,' "{}" \;
```

With BSD sed:

```
find . -name "*ctl" -type f -exec sed -i '' -e 's,^M,,' "{}" \;
```

`^M` in sed argument is a literal Control-M, not ASCII `^` followed `M`. Press <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> and then <kbd>M</kbd> to enter it.

Comment: I use to write the sed with s/<find>/<replace> combination but this looks different. Could you explain

Comment: You can use any characters in `sed` expression.

Answer (score 2):

[dos2unix](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dos2unix) was born to solve this problem.

You can locate all the target files by find or whatever program, then

```
dos2unix filename
```

**Background of this problem** (by [Dominique](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4279155/dominique) )

Let's explain what this is about: in UNIX, ENTER is translated as chr(13) (ASCII-code of carriage return), in DOS (Windows) ENTER is translated as chr(13)+chr(10) (carriage return combined with newline character). When you open a Windows textfile in UNIX, you see that chr(10) character (which you don't want). The mentioned dos2unix command searches for that chr(13)+chr(10) and removes the chr(10) characters. – Dominique

Comment: @Dominique thanks, I added the comment in the answer.